# Using same MouseListener event for multiple actions, drawing in java swing

Tags: java, swing, draw, mouselistener

Im still in the process of learning java in general so I could use some help.
I've created a popup menu that opens when I leftclick on the panel. Popup menu uses MouseListener to read the coordinates where it needs to open.
Now I would like to use same x and y where popup menu opened to draw a shape that I choose from the menu in that position(if the shape is a point, it should be drawn where menu opened, if I choose a line per say, starting point of the line would be in that position). Here's the code so far:

```
public class PnlDrawing extends JPanel {
public ArrayList<Shape> shapes = new ArrayList<Shape>();

public PnlDrawing() {
    setSize(800,600);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("PnlDrawing");
    frame.setSize(800, 600);
    PnlDrawing drawing = new PnlDrawing();
    frame.getContentPane().add(drawing);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    
    final JMenu subPopup = new JMenu("Add");
    
    final JMenuItem popPoint = new JMenuItem("Point");
    popPoint.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    final JMenuItem popLine = new JMenuItem("Line");
    popLine.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    final JMenuItem popCircle = new JMenuItem("Circle");
    popCircle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    final JMenuItem popDonut = new JMenuItem("Donut");
    popDonut.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    final JMenuItem popRectangle = new JMenuItem("Rectangle");
    popRectangle.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    
    final JMenuItem popMod = new JMenuItem("Modify");
    popMod.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    final JMenuItem popRemove = new JMenuItem("Remove");
    popRemove.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
        }
    });
    
    frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(e)) {
                JPopupMenu mainPopup = new JPopupMenu();
                subPopup.add(popPoint);
                subPopup.add(popLine);
                subPopup.add(popCircle);
                subPopup.add(popDonut);
                subPopup.add(popRectangle);
                mainPopup.add(subPopup);
                mainPopup.addSeparator();
                mainPopup.add(popMod);
                mainPopup.add(popRemove);
                mainPopup.show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++)
    {
        shapes.get(i).draw(g);
    }
}
```

}

I have implemented classes for each shape and draw methods. I just need to connect this menu with the drawing and mouse position so it appears on the panel when I click Add -> Point for instance.
If you have any other ways of doing all of this, I'll gladly hear it.

Answer (score 2):

1. All of your code should NOT be contained in the main() method. All the main() method should do is create the frame and add an instance of your "DrawingPanel" to the frame. Use descriptive names for you classes. There is no reason to use "Pnl" as an abbreviation.
2. All the rest of the logic in the main() method should be moved to the DrawingPanel class.
3. Custom painting is done by overriding the paintComponent(...) method of the DrawingPanel class. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for working example to get you started. Use the tutorial example as the starting point since it will demonstrate a better structure for your code so all the components are created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`.
4. A popup menu is typically displayed when a right click is used. Read the section from the tutorial on [Bringup Up a Popup Menu](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#popup).
5. Don't recreate the popup menu in the MouseListener each time. Create the popup in the constructor of your class and just show it when necessary.

> Now I would like to use same x and y where popup menu opened to draw a shape

Create an instance variable in your class like "mousePressed". Then is the mousePressed event of your mouse listener you can update the "mousePressed" variable to reflect the mouse position. Then all your ActionListener will reference this variable when adding the Shape to the List.